Unable to add existing nsg to vm using azure bicep
param existingnsg string = 'mytestnsg'
resource nsg1 'Microsoft.network/networksecuritygroups@2022-01-08 ' existing = {
  name :'existing nsg'
}

module testvm.\vm.bicep = {
name : testimony
location: 'Norway west'
nsg: nsg1.id
}

Unable to add existing nsg to vm using azure bicep.

Hi Satish, could you share the content of your vm.bicep file please? Also did you receive any specific error ?

Also from your code you are not using the existingnsg parameter ?


Unable to add existing nsg to vm using azure bicep.

I agree with Thomas, you can add a parameter for using an existing NSG.

param  networkSecurityGroupId  string = '/subscriptions/158b8345-c359-4d98-95c5-f21815dd048f/resourcegroups/Venkat/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/Venkat-nsg'


Here is the updated Bicep code to create a VM with an existing NSG
@description('Username for the Virtual Machine.')
param adminUsername string

@description('Password for the Virtual Machine.')
@minLength(12)
@secure()
param adminPassword string

@description('Unique DNS Name for the Public IP used to access the Virtual Machine.')
param dnsLabelPrefix string = toLower('${vmName}-${uniqueString(resourceGroup().id, vmName)}')

@description('Name for the Public IP used to access the Virtual Machine.')
param publicIpName string = 'myPublicIP'

@description('Allocation method for the Public IP used to access the Virtual Machine.')
@allowed([
  'Dynamic'
  'Static'
])
param publicIPAllocationMethod string = 'Dynamic'

@description('SKU for the Public IP used to access the Virtual Machine.')
@allowed([
  'Basic'
  'Standard'
])
param publicIpSku string = 'Basic'

@description('The Windows version for the VM. This will pick a fully patched image of this given Windows version.')
@allowed([
  '2016-datacenter-gensecond'
  '2016-datacenter-server-core-g2'
  '2016-datacenter-server-core-smalldisk-g2'
  '2016-datacenter-smalldisk-g2'
  '2016-datacenter-with-containers-g2'
  '2016-datacenter-zhcn-g2'
  '2019-datacenter-core-g2'
  '2019-datacenter-core-smalldisk-g2'
  '2019-datacenter-core-with-containers-g2'
  '2019-datacenter-core-with-containers-smalldisk-g2'
  '2019-datacenter-gensecond'
  '2019-datacenter-smalldisk-g2'
  '2019-datacenter-with-containers-g2'
  '2019-datacenter-with-containers-smalldisk-g2'
  '2019-datacenter-zhcn-g2'
  '2022-datacenter-azure-edition'
  '2022-datacenter-azure-edition-core'
  '2022-datacenter-azure-edition-core-smalldisk'
  '2022-datacenter-azure-edition-smalldisk'
  '2022-datacenter-core-g2'
  '2022-datacenter-core-smalldisk-g2'
  '2022-datacenter-g2'
  '2022-datacenter-smalldisk-g2'
])
param OSVersion string = '2022-datacenter-azure-edition'

@description('Size of the virtual machine.')
param vmSize string = 'Standard_D2s_v5'

@description('Location for all resources.')
param location string = resourceGroup().location

@description('Name of the virtual machine.')
param vmName string = 'simple-vm'

@description('Security Type of the Virtual Machine.')
@allowed([
  'Standard'
  'TrustedLaunch'
])
param securityType string = 'TrustedLaunch'

@description('ID of the existing Network Security Group to associate with the VM.')
param networkSecurityGroupId string = '/subscriptions/158b8345-c359-4d98-95c5-f21815dd048f/resourcegroups/Venkat/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/Venkat-nsg'

var storageAccountName = 'bootdiags${uniqueString(resourceGroup().id)}'
var nicName = 'myVMNic'
var addressPrefix = '10.0.0.0/16'
var subnetName = 'Subnet'
var subnetPrefix = '10.0.0.0/24'
var virtualNetworkName = 'MyVNET'
var securityProfileJson = {
  uefiSettings: {
    secureBootEnabled: true
    vTpmEnabled: true
  }
  securityType: securityType
}

resource storageAccount 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts@2022-05-01' = {
  name: storageAccountName
  location: location
  sku: {
    name: 'Standard_LRS'
  }
  kind: 'Storage'
}

resource publicIp 'Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses@2022-05-01' = {
  name: publicIpName
  location: location
  sku: {
    name: publicIpSku
  }
  properties: {
    publicIPAllocationMethod: publicIPAllocationMethod
    dnsSettings: {
      domainNameLabel: dnsLabelPrefix
    }
  }
}

resource virtualNetwork 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks@2022-05-01' = {
  name: virtualNetworkName
  location: location
  properties: {
    addressSpace: {
      addressPrefixes: [
        addressPrefix
      ]
    }
    subnets: [
      {
        name: subnetName
        properties: {
          addressPrefix: subnetPrefix
          networkSecurityGroup: {
            id: networkSecurityGroupId
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}

resource nic 'Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces@2022-05-01' = {
  name: nicName
  location: location
  properties: {
    ipConfigurations: [
      {
        name: 'ipconfig1'
        properties: {
          privateIPAllocationMethod: 'Dynamic'
          publicIPAddress: {
            id: publicIp.id
          }
          subnet: {
            id: resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets', virtualNetworkName, subnetName)
          }
        }
      }
    ]
    networkSecurityGroup: {
      id: networkSecurityGroupId
    }
  }
  dependsOn: [
    virtualNetwork
  ]
}

resource vm 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines@2022-03-01' = {
  name: vmName
  location: location
  properties: {
    hardwareProfile: {
      vmSize: vmSize
    }
    osProfile: {
      computerName: vmName
      adminUsername: adminUsername
      adminPassword: adminPassword
    }
    storageProfile: {
      imageReference: {
        publisher: 'MicrosoftWindowsServer'
        offer: 'WindowsServer'
        sku: OSVersion
        version: 'latest'
      }
      osDisk: {
        createOption: 'FromImage'
        managedDisk: {
          storageAccountType: 'StandardSSD_LRS'
        }
      }
      dataDisks: [
        {
          diskSizeGB: 1023
          lun: 0
          createOption: 'Empty'
        }
      ]
    }
    networkProfile: {
      networkInterfaces: [
        {
          id: nic.id
        }
      ]
    }
    securityProfile: (securityType == 'TrustedLaunch' ? securityProfileJson : null)
  }
}

Output:

Existing NSG

Reference: Bicep file

Issue resolved thanks
